# How to get the file size and file type of uploaded file using cordova camera plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to get the type and size of uploaded file using cordova camera plugin. I am using the following code

```
var source='';
if(sourceSelection==0){
   source=Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
}
else if(sourceSelection==1){
   source=Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
}
navigator.camera.getPicture(
      function onSuccess(imageData) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageData, function success(fileEntry) {

          // Do something with the FileEntry object, like write to it, upload it, etc.
          // writeFile(fileEntry, imgUri);
          console.log("got file: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
          // displayFileData(fileEntry.nativeURL, "Native URL");

        }, function (err) {
          console.log(err);
          // If don't get the FileEntry (which may happen when testing
          // on some emulators), copy to a new FileEntry.
          // createNewFileEntry(imgUri);
        });
        $timeout(function () {
          service.imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + imageData;
          service.imageUploaded = true;
          resolve({
            imgUrl:service.imageUrl
          });
        }, 0);

      }, function onFail(message) {
        reject(false);
      },
      {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        // encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        sourceType: source,
        allowEdit: true,
        correctOrientation:true,
        targetHeight:100,
        targetWidth:200
  });
```

But when it comes to the window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL fuction it always fails and never goes into the success callback function. When I check the error it says

```
"A URI supplied to the API was malformed, or the resulting Data URL has exceeded the URL length limitations for Data URLs."
```

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you get back from getPicture is not a file but a base64 encoded string.
You can then save it as follows:

```
  this.myCamera.getPicture(this.myCameraOptions).then((imageData) => {

    // store in gallery
    this.myBase64.base64ToGallery(imageData, { prefix: '_img' })
    .then( (data) => {
      // success
    }, (dataErr) => {
      // error
    });
  }, (dataErr) => {
      // error
  });
```